# How to add an alpha value to each pixel of a Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, alpha

I am following a tutorial in image recognition https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ry9AzwTMwJQ&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDffXBfcH9ZJuvctJV3OtB8A&index=9

But the code built is made to compare images that have an alpha value and the image I want to test doesn't have alpha value.

I have tried a lot of things, here is how my last try looks like :

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np 

i = Image.open('images/test.png')
iar = np.array(i)

def addAlpha(iar):
    b = []
    for eachRow in iar:
        b += [[255]]
    for eachRow in iar:
        eachRow = np.append(eachRow, b, axis= 1)

        print(eachRow)

    print (iar)

    return iar

iar = addAlpha(iar)
```

So when I print eachRow It looks like how I want it to be, but when I print iar nothing has changed, there are still only the RGB values.

I already thank you for any help and I apology for my bad English !

Comment: What is `iar`'s shape? (Check `iar.shape`)

Comment: Printing iar.shape gives : (8, 8, 3)

Answer (score 1):

Given that `iar`'s shape is 8x8x3, we can tell we're working with an 8x8 image where each pixel has three channels (r, g, and b). We'd like to add a fourth channel for alpha, which will bring our shape to 8x8x4.

First, we create an array that contains all our alpha values:

```
alpha = 255 * np.ones((8, 8, 1))
```

Here, we create an 8x8 array of ones (with an extra dimension to make its axes line up with `iar`) and multiply it by `255` to give it the value we want.

Now, we can simply [concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) the two arrays:

```
iar = np.concatenate([iar, alpha], axis=2)
```

We concatenate along axis 2 which is what essentially lets us "paste" the `alpha` array to the back of `iar`, adding our fourth channel to the image.

[Here](https://repl.it/repls/FrequentDarkmagentaMatch) it is in action.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it did work well but it added some '.' before my values. I found a solution using this : `iar = np.concatenate((iar, np.full( (8, 8, 1), 255, dtype= int)), axis = 2)`